# Do down-votes influence the amount of spam-flags required for spam-deletion?

Tags: support, down-votes, flags, spam

As [previously mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62050/please-help-de-spamming-sciencestack), we're trying to de-spam [ScienceStack](http://science.stackexchange.com). Should I also down-vote spam or is flagging sufficient to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flagging is sufficient.

Keep in mind that after six flags it is deleted anyway, so downvoting it won't add any value that I can think of.